# Disk shortcuts open in text editor rather than file explorer

Tags: 18.04, files, shortcuts

When I try to open attached disks in the file explorer, it seems to try and open the folder in a text editor. How can I fix this so that the drive shortcut opens in file explorer?

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ0wI.png) of the issue; I double click on the 'Data' shortcut and a text editor window pops up rather than the file explorer.

The same happens when I open file explorer and try to open the 'Data' disk from the 'Other Locations' area ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHqq1.png)). I can view the files on the disk if I navigate to the mount location, but this is a tad inconvenient.